Dynamic colspan mix object with string, numbers, date string in C# javascript
The issue is in bottom and top performance columns are dynamic, I need to set colspan by dynamic no of columns, I select 1 to no of months of period (mm-yyyy) in 2023 or other year. abc to region static or fixed columns. Please check dummy snippet.
My requirements are:

colspan dynamic
Bottom performance - background red
Top performance - background green
01-2023 (mm-yyyy) format to Jan-2023
01-20231: remove last 1 and make it Jan-2023 - from all columns remove 1

I have JSON data like this:
var ReportResult = [
{
    "01-2023": "100", "02-2023" : "100", "01-20231" : "100", "02-20231" : "100", "03-2023" : "100", "03-20231" : "100", "abc" : "ALL", "abc_max" : "ALL", "xyz" : "ALL", "xyz_max" : "ALL"
}
]

And my code is:
var ReportResult = [{
  "01-2023": "100",
  "02-2023": "100",
  "01-20231": "100",
  "02-20231": "100",
  "03-2023": "100",
  "03-20231": "100",
  "abc": "ALL",
  "abc_max": "ALL",
  "xyz": "ALL",
  "xyz_max": "ALL"
}];

var selector = document.getElementById("customTable");
var columns = addAllColumnHeaders(ReportResult, selector);

for (var i = 0; i < ReportResult.length; i++) {
  var row$ = $('<tr/>');
  for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < columns.length; colIndex++) {
    var cellValue = ReportResult[i][columns[colIndex]];
    if (cellValue == null) cellValue = "";
    row$.append($('<td style="padding: 8px; border-left: 1px solid #ededed; border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed; " />').html(cellValue));
  }
  $(selector).append(row$);
}

function addAllColumnHeaders(ReportResult, selector) {
  var columnSet = [];
  var headerTr$ = $('<tr/>');

  var Topheader$ = $('<tr />');
  Topheader$.append($('<th colspan="4" />'));
  Topheader$.append($('<th class="Bottom_performer" style="padding: 8px; border-left: 1px solid #ededed; border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;" />').html("Bottom Performance"));
  Topheader$.append($('<th class="Bottom_performer" style="padding: 8px; border-left: 1px solid #ededed; border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;" />').html("Top Performance"));
  for (var i = 0; i < ReportResult.length; i++) {
    var rowHash = ReportResult[i];
    for (var key in rowHash) {
      if ($.inArray(key, columnSet) == -1) {

        columnSet.push(key);
        headerTr$.append($('<th style="padding: 8px; border-left: 1px solid #ededed; border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;" />').html(key));

      }
    }
  }
  $(selector).append(Topheader$);
  $(selector).append(headerTr$);

  return columnSet;
}

.Bottom_performer {
  background: red;
}

.Top_performer {
  background: green;
}

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="customTable"></table>

Desired output:
.Bottom_performer {
  background: red;
}

.Top_performer {
  background: green;
}


<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="4"></th>
    <th colspan="3" class="Bottom_performer" style="padding: 8px; border-left: 1px solid #ededed; border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;">Bottom Performance</th>
    <th colspan="3" class="Top_performer" style="padding: 8px; border-left: 1px solid #ededed; border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;">Top Performance</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th style="padding: 8px; border-left: 1px solid #ededed; border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;">abc</th>
    <th style="padding: 8px; border-left: 1px solid #ededed; border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;">xyz</th>
    <th style="padding: 8px; border-left: 1px solid #ededed; border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;">ProFamily</th>
    <th style="padding: 8px; border-left: 1px solid #ededed; border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;">Region</th>
    <th style="padding: 8px; border-left: 1px solid #ededed; border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;">01-2023</th>
    <th style="padding: 8px; border-left: 1px solid #ededed; border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;">02-2023</th>
    <th style="padding: 8px; border-left: 1px solid #ededed; border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;"> no of columns</th>
    <th style="padding: 8px; border-left: 1px solid #ededed; border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;">01-20231</th>
    <th style="padding: 8px; border-left: 1px solid #ededed; border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;">02-20231</th>
    <th style="padding: 8px; border-left: 1px solid #ededed; border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;">no of columns</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding: 8px; border-left: 1px solid #ededed; border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed; ">ALL</td>
    <td style="padding: 8px; border-left: 1px solid #ededed; border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed; ">ALL</td>
    <td style="padding: 8px; border-left: 1px solid #ededed; border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed; ">ALL</td>
    <td style="padding: 8px; border-left: 1px solid #ededed; border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed; ">ALL</td>
    <td style="padding: 8px; border-left: 1px solid #ededed; border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed; ">100</td>
    <td style="padding: 8px; border-left: 1px solid #ededed; border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed; ">100</td>
    <td style="padding: 8px; border-left: 1px solid #ededed; border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed; ">no of data</td>
    <td style="padding: 8px; border-left: 1px solid #ededed; border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed; ">100</td>
    <td style="padding: 8px; border-left: 1px solid #ededed; border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed; ">100</td>
    <td style="padding: 8px; border-left: 1px solid #ededed; border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed; ">no of data</td>
  </tr>
</table>

Thanks in advance, anybody please help me. I try with lots of time.

Please be more specific about the columns and data. For example: 1-Are the Bottom Performance columns have 4-digit year and Top performance ones have 5-digit (an additional 1 at end)? 2-When ReportResult has multiple records, do all of them have same column order? If so, it is easy to achieve this with simpler code.

Thanks for your Help, The issue has been resolve.
